How to make TextBlock inside UserControl readable by Narrator in WPF
Narrator is not reading the TextBlock inside a UserControl:
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        
      <TextBlock Text="Test text" Focusable="True" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Test_text" />

    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>

If I am changing the TextBlock to Button, the Narrator is capable of reading it. What options do I have to make this readable by Narrator other than making buttons that look like labels?

I am guessing: Narrator is not reading everything, but something you need to interract with. This answer suggests to make control focusable, try it.

@Sinatr the control is focusable. You can see the code sample above, it is the TextBlock.

What does Narrator reads exactly? The text of element what has keyboard focus? Then you need to set focus explicitly by calling Focus() or using Tab key (you have Focusable=true already for Tab-key to work). Maybe an easier solution is to use Label instead of TextBlock, they are quite similar controls. This answer points out that Label supports access key (same as Button), so maybe this is, what Narrator checks and what TextBlock doesn't provide, therefore being ignored?
